# this.state won't update as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to update the state of my component. It fetches some data on initial mounting as expected with `componentDidMount()`. I have a `componentDidUpdate()` that compares `prevProps` and `this.state`and will "re-fetch" as expected. However, between those moments, I don't know when to re-fetch because the `prevProps` and `this.state` become equal since the `this.state` doesn't update (again, because idk where to place the fetching of new data).

This is on the client side of the reactjs app.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = ({ x:0 })
}

componentDidMount(){
  fetchingdata()
  this.setState({x:data[x]})
}

componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps, snapshot){
  if(prevProps.x !== this.state.x){
    return fetchingdata()
  }
}

render(){
  return(
    <div> this.state.x </div>
  )
}
```

If you were to `console.log(this.state.x)` in `componentDidUpdate()` it'll be on the current value even if the server side is fully updated. basically the `prevProps` updates, the `this.state` updates only upon loading because of `componentDidMount()` and then the server updates and doesn't know where to send the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need to show more code with a clearer explanation on what you expect to happen. Take a look at the page on how to create a [mcve] for some helpful advice on fleshing out your question.

Comment: Does `fetchingdata()` return a Promise?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the latest update to some data in your component from a remote server. If that is what you want to achieve, you can simply poll the server every x seconds with `setInterval()`.
Do this in your `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        const data = this.fetchData() // Return result of an ajax call
        this.setState({myData: data})
    }, 1000) // Replace x with what suits you

}
```

Also remember to clear interval in your `componentWillUnmount()`

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
 }
```

Comment: thank you! sorry for not being clear, I would like to update it when I click a button. My problem is that typically you would setState() upon the button click action, however, this button is in the main app while this state is in a different file due to UI (didn't want the button and the response in the same box)

Comment: If your components have a parent child hierarchy, you can pass parent state as prop  down to your child component. Updating state of parent component will update props on child component. If that is not the case, you would need a global app state.
Something like Redux.

Comment: Thank you! could you elaborate please with an example? I'm very new to this. in my other file I have a basic handleSubmit function that literally posts a date to my server. server makes the call, but then doesn't know where to send the data. that's the crux of my struggle.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems appears to be here:

```
render(){
  return(
     <div> this.state.x </div>
  )
}
```

In react, in order to access a state you have to use "{}" to enter javascript when in the render area. This is actually one of the great things about react in general. This allows you to access variables from the state or even any javascript in between the "render(){" and the "return()" area.

One of the causes of the data not returning is not accessing a javascript environment because it's rendering "this.state.x" as text rather than the state.

Try

```
render(){
  return(
   <div> {this.state.x} </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please use promise for API fetching,
please check componentDidMount

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = ({ x:0 })
}

componentDidMount(){
  fetchingdata()
   .then((res) => {
      this.setState({x:res[x]}) 
   })
}

componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps, snapshot){
  if(prevProps.x !== this.state.x){
    return fetchingdata()
  }
}

render(){
  return(
    <div> this.state.x </div>
  )
}
```